# The content of element type "interceptor" must match "(param)*"

Tags: xml, configuration, struts2, interceptor, dtd

I am working struts2.5.5 using Maven.

I got an error in Interceptor tag:

> The content of element type `"interceptor"` must match `"(param)*"`

in struts.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd"> 
<struts>
   <package name="default" namespace="/action" extends="struts-default">
      <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="AuthenticationInterceptor">
        <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
       </interceptor>
     </interceptors>
     <action name="login">
       <result>login.jsp</result>
     </action>
     <action name="LoginAction" class="LoginAction">
       <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
         <param name="actionName">task</param>
         <param name="namespace">/action</param>
       </result>
       <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
     </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interceptor element is not closed:

```xml
<interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="AuthenticationInterceptor">
```

hence it's trying to take the `<interceptor-stack>` declaration as body, while he expects only the `<param>` elemen in that position.

Just self-close the tag:

```xml
<interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="AuthenticationInterceptor" />
```